# re.sub greedy characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to remove text from my strings that start with `"\"`, such as:

```
 \xf, \africa\87, \ckat\x70, ...
```

Is there a way of doing this using greedy characters in `re.sub`?

e.g.:

```
line = re.sub("[\.*]", "", line)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
input example:

```
" lorem ipsum \xe2\x80\x9csianhill7 lorem ipsum"
```

output:

```
" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
```

Comment: You should probably add an input and output example.

Comment: Is `\xe2` really `\xe2`, or does it mean the character with ASCII code 0xe2?

Comment: I believe it means the character with ASCII code 0xe2 but it appears as \xe2 in my text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove all non-ascii prefixes words from your sentences

You can easily do it through a `single pass LC` with `ordinal match` and `filter` without employing `regex`

```
>>> data = " lorem ipsum \xe2\x80\x9csianhill7 lorem ipsum"
>>> ' '.join(e for e in data.split() if 31 < ord(e[0]) < 127)
'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum'
```

Comment: I guess `31 < ord(e[0]) < 127` is better, since `chr(31)=='\x1f'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks ... Point Taken

Answer (score 1):

The expression to match is:

```
[\b\\][\w]+,?
```

And using your input text of lorem ipsum the above expression does match only the inner words you want to remove :)

[example rubular](http://rubular.com/r/MUtEt8fabw)

I have added some other regex to match `,` inside the string and used `*` for 0 or more after the `\`

```
[\b\\][\w.,]*
```

[another example](http://rubular.com/r/BdGSw5qwxP)

Comment: Using line = re.sub("[\b^\\][\w]+,?", "", line) actually removes everything else but the strings that start with "\"... I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, same problem again, it only keeps the strings starting with \ and removes everything else

Comment: The I reckon you are calling the wrong method to remove/keep the result - rubular isolates the correct part you just have to use the right method on the regex. I looked at the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html and I think your call to .sub is missing args

Comment: EDIT: use `[\b\\][\w.,]*` - typo in last edit damn `^` I thought I had removed

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
                    \\\S+\s*
                    """, re.VERBOSE)
line = r" lorem ipsum \xe2\x80\x9csianhill7 lorem ipsum"
replaced = regex.sub("", line)
```

Note that you need to tell python to treat the '\' as regular character not as escape character. This is done by adding the r in front of the string.

I also assume that you want to remove all the text beginning with '\' up to and including the next white-space characters.

Comment: thank you, though I can't really add "r" in front of the string since i import it with open('... .csv')

Comment: If you're reading directly from a file, than there is no need for the 'r'. It is needed only if you want to test the code on isolated example.